# Add a MappingExpression for already created Map

Tags: c#, automapper

[AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki) allows to customize the map through the `IMappingExpression` returned by the `CreateMap` method. Like this:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DifferentPropB, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PropertyB));
```

Is there a way to get the `IMapperExpression` for a mapper already created to further customize the mapping?

I'm thinking about something like this:

```cs
/* Somewhere in my code */
Mapper.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>();

/* Somewhere else in my code */
Mapper.GetMappingExpressionFor<ClassA, ClassB>().
    ForMember(dest => dest.DifferentPropB, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PropertyB));
```

Of course the `GetMappingExpressionFor` doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're asking for. So you have a mapping of two types....but you want to FURTHER customize...that mapping? When you first create the mapping... Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>() ...that in itself RETURNS a mapping expression...can't you just use that...

Comment: Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<Source, Destination>(); is the only thing I can find relative to what you need.